# Php file definition with variables

Tags: php, fopen, fedex

I am modifying FedEx's API files to fit my site, and I am struggling to make the definitions dynamic based on the total number of packages.

```
$totalPackages = 4;
for($i=1; $i<=($totalPackages-1); $i++) {
    define('SHIP_CHILDLABEL_'.$i, 'shipchildlabel_'.$i.'pdf');
}
```

Later on in the file...

```
for($i=1; $i<=($totalPackages-1); $i++) {
    $fp = fopen(SHIP_CHILDLABEL_.$i, 'wb');
    fwrite($fp, ($childResponse->CompletedShipmentDetail->CompletedPackageDetails->Label->Parts->Image));
    fclose($fp);
    echo '<a href="./'.SHIP_CHILDLABEL_.$i.'.pdf">'.SHIP_CHILDLABEL_.$i.'</a> was generated';
}
```

Of course, this causes fopen to reference SHIP_CHILDLABEL_1.pdf, SHIP_CHILDLABEL_2.pdf, and SHIP_CHILDLABEL_3.pdf instead of shipchildlabel_1.pdf, shipchildlabel_2.pdf, and shipchildlabel_3.pdf.  How can I properly make these definitions dynamic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `constant`:

```
$fp = fopen(constant('SHIP_CHILDLABEL_'.$i), 'wb');
```

[Docs here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php)

Comment: Yes, this is perfect.  Thanks for letting me know about contant().  I will mark this correct in 9 mins when I can. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Try using "constant" directive for handling dynamic constant names (defines).

For example:

```
$i = 1;
define("CONSTANT_".$i, 123);
echo constant("CONSTANT".$i);
```

This will do the trick.

Regards